# php file_get_contents (comma separated values) to array

Tags: php, arrays

My web api is returning following

```
"timestamp","full_message"
"2017-09-06T21:54:00.853Z","Device 192.168.1.1 is unstable"
"2017-09-06T21:54:01.069Z","Device 192.168.22.20  is unstable"
"2017-09-06T21:54:01.069Z","Device 192.168.22.18  is unstable"
```

I want to pass this to array looking like this

```
["Device 192.168.1.1 is unstable","Device 192.168.22.20  is unstable","Device 192.168.22.18  is unstable"]
```

Want to get rid of most of the things except device information.
API is from graylog so no control over the output.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Instead of using `file_get_contents`, open the API using `fopen()`. Then you can write a loop that use `fgetcsv()` to read each line into an array.

Comment: This is a csv file .. so you should use fgetcsv like @Barmar  wrotr

Comment: `explode("\n", $filecontents);` and then loop through it, echoing `values[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already pointed out you could implement a cleaner and more reliable solution using `fopen()` and `fgetcsv()`.

Anyway... a possible implementation with `file_get_contents()` could be:

```
// This is your data
$data = file_get_contents(...)
// Split $data by "\n"
$lines = explode("\n", $data);
// Get rid of first element of array, which will always (?) be "timestamp","full_message"
array_shift($lines);
// Prepare variable $output
$output = Array();
// Fill $output array with the information you are looking for
foreach ($lines as $line) // for each $line in array $lines
{
    $tokens = explode(",", $line); // split $line by "," and store array result in $tokens
    $output[] = $tokens[1]; // push the second element of $tokens in $output
}
// Done, now $output is your array
```

Assuming that your input data will **always** be like the example you posted. Otherwise consider making a couple more controls on the input.